# Automating responsive design using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to automate responsive design testing using Selenium Webdriver? Can it be done with chrome options or a library of some sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following sample of Java Code with JUnit:-

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class ResponsiveWebTest {


    public WebDriver driver;
    public List<Dimension> screenDimensionsList;


    @Before
    public void beforeTestMethod(){

        // create list of dimensions for various screen sizes
        screenDimensionsList = new ArrayList<Dimension>();
        screenDimensionsList.add(new Dimension(1600,800));
        screenDimensionsList.add(new Dimension(1200,800));
        screenDimensionsList.add(new Dimension(992,800));
        screenDimensionsList.add(new Dimension(768,800));
        screenDimensionsList.add(new Dimension(480,800));
        screenDimensionsList.add(new Dimension(360,800));

        // initialize the driver for browser
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://nandal.in");
    }

    @Test
    public void testVariousScreenSizes(){

        for(Dimension d: screenDimensionsList){
             driver.manage().window().setSize(d);
             // run some test cases for this screen size
             // some test case steps

             try{
                 Thread.sleep(2000);
             }catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will open chrome browser with given url, and then resizes the browser according to the dimensions list to test the responsive behavior of the webpage, You can add your test logic there.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Using this example I can modify it for Python and C# too.